# how to add style in Dropdownlistfor helper in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

Want to add style with onchange function in dropdownlist my code is something like this :-

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.printEmployeeCardDTO.DataCardConnectionType,null,new {    @onchange="_printEmployeeCard.GetPrintersDetail(this.value, printersList);" },new    { style = "width: 100px;" }  )
```

I m getting error in this. Could anyone help me in it?

Comment: What error are you getting? Please edit it into your question.

Answer (score 2):

You used two different parameters `new { }` instead of only one separated by `,`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.printEmployeeCardDTO.DataCardConnectionType,
    null,
    new { @onchange="_printEmployeeCard.GetPrintersDetail(this.value, printersList);", style = "width: 100px;" }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `@` sign with the style attribute, like this:

```
@style = "width: 100px;"
```